# Jade + express Failed to lookup view in views directory

Tags: node.js, pug

this question has been asked a couple of times before, but i can't seem to solve this based on other answers. so whatever i do i seem to keep getting `Failed to lookup view "API" in views directory "/Users/MYUSER/Desktop/matchmaking/app/views"`. even though the path seem right?

**file structure**

```
├───app
│   └───bin
│   └───models
│   └───node_modules
│   └───public
│   │   └───images
│   │   └───javascripts
│   │   └───stylesheets
│   └───routes
│   │   └───index
│   │   └───groups
│   │   └───index
│   │   └───users
│   └───views
│   │   └───error.jade
│   │   └───index.jade
│   │   └───layout.jade
│   └───app.js
│   └───package.json
│   └───config.js
│   └───upload.js
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var games = require('./routes/games');
var groups = require('./routes/groups');

var jwt    = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config = require('./config'); // get our config file

var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.database); // connect to our database



var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/api', routes);
app.use('/api/users', users);
app.use('/api/games', games);
app.use('/api/groups', groups);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var graph = require('fbgraph');
var User = require('../models/user');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var request = require('request');
var uploader  = require('../upload');
var config = require('../config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');



/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('API', { title: 'Welcome to the api' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install jade

```
npm install jade
```

make sure there is views/API.jade, if you are rendering this page...please show the controller code

in your controller you are rendering API.JADE res.render(**"API"**,..

create a file in views folder .. API.jade

```
**API.jade**


extends layout
block content
h1= title
p Welcome to #{title}
```

Comment: i've now added `var jade = require('jade');` and it is allready installed with `npm install jade --save` no change

Comment: you have installed this app from express generator... would please check is there jade directory inside node_modules ...

Comment: yes i used express generator then i removed jade to try `pug` and then reinstalled jade and it gave this error

Comment: and there i a jade folder in node_modules

Comment: error clear that the Failed to lookup view "API" in views directory ...mean you are rendering API.jade in your controller.. would you please share the code of Controller

Comment: i've added `index.js`, which should be equal to `/api` route that i'm calling